# didDiscoverPeripheral never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have two devices `(ipad 3 and iphone 4s)`, and was trying to find a way to recognize one of the two devices (For future exchange information between them), for that, I'm with active Bluetooth devices in 2, and using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    CBUUID *otherDevice = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"];


    NSDictionary *scanOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];


    self.mgr = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    [self.mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:otherDevice] options:scanOptions];

}

#pragma mark - delegates

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {


    NSLog(@"I found new devices ->  %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[advertisementData description]]);
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    NSLog(@"This is it!");
}


- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    NSString *messtoshow;

    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        {
            messtoshow=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bluetooth is currently powered on and available to use."];
            [self.mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
            break;
        }   

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",messtoshow);
}
```

The problem with this code is that I am getting the message on the console that bluetooth is active, but the method 'didDiscoverPeripheral:' not being called, why this is happening? (since the Bluetooth on both devices are active)?

Comment: Your first call to `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` will fail because you are calling it too soon - you can't call this method until your central is in the powered on state.  You also need an app on the other device to advertise a service using CBPeripheralManager before you will see it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I try to run this tutorial in my ipad 3 and my iphone, one is central and other peripheral, and not occurred , I try this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

Comment: @Paulw11 I test too this project given by the made of the tutorial in my devices... https://github.com/orepereira/CoreBluetooth

Comment: @Paulw11, and don't work too... I put my iphone to central and ipad to peripheral, in console log the iphone says the message 'Scanning started' but not occurred, can you test in your devices?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Suggestion by @Paulw11 and Tushar below doesn't help. Also, when I use `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil` it works. It just doesn't work when I specify a specific service. iPhone 4s in periph mode and mac in central mode. The logger shows that the iPhone sends some packet (`LE Advertising Report`)

Comment: @tofi9 How are you advertising your service on your phone?  This question is related to CBCentral, but from your description I suspect that your problem is in your CBPeripheral code.  You could ask another question and provide the code where you advertise your peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm advertising the peripheral on the phone, callback `peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising` comes back with no error.  Works when `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil`. I have to say that I use many beta software (xcode 6.3 beta/yosemite RTM/iphone 4s ios8.3 beta). See code for both sides https://github.com/tofi9/bt-issue

Comment: Your code works for me - at first it wasn't but then I realised that the BT was flakey on my iPhone - So I restarted it and it ran straight away.  I am not using any beta though.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I think it's on the Mac side. I've managed to get it working by calling `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSUUID(...)]` **mind the `NSUUID` instead of `CBUUID`**. Only found out by wildly trying things, as the call using `CBUUID` doesn't crash nor does it display an error. The documentation clearly specifies `CBUUID`. I will be filing a bug report with Apple. Not sure whether it is the Yosemite stack (doubt it) or the swift runtime (version 1.2) that refuses to do an automatic conversion between `CBUUID` and `NSUUID` (I would have to test using objective-c to rule this out)